# Why is the value of foo.x undefined in foo.x = foo = {n: 2}?

Tags: javascript

This code:

```
var foo = {n: 1};
var bar = foo;
foo.x = foo = {n: 2};
```

Can you please explain what is meant by:

```
foo.x = foo = {n: 2};
```

I see that `{n:2}` is assigned to `foo`. Why is `undefined` assigned to `foo.x`? Does `foo = {n: 2};` return `undefined`?

Comment: Why the downvote? This is an interesting question.

Comment: @Juhana would you mind fixing your edit?

Comment: @djechlin What's wrong with it?

Comment: @Juhana you reverted formatting and language improvements.

Comment: Done, manually merged.

Comment: @djechlin I fail to see how "This code" is an improvement but YMMV.

Comment: It thought it looked weird to start off the body with a code block instead of some natural language. Improvements are welcome.

Answer (score 25):

[According to the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation), the left hand side of an assignment expression is evaluated first, even though the operator has right-to-left precedence.  Thus the expression `foo.x = foo = {n: 2}` which is the same as `foo.x = (foo = {n: 2})` is evaluated like this:

1. Evaluate the left-hand expression `foo.x` to get a reference, which is where the value of the right-hand expression will be assigned to.
2. Evaluate the right-hand expression, to to get the value that will be assigned. The right-hand side is another assignment expression, so it gets evaluated the same way:

   1. Evaluate `foo` to determine where to assign to.
   2. Evaluate the expression `{n:2}`, which creates an object, to determine the value to assign.
   3. Assign `{n:2}` to foo, and return `{n:2}`.
3. Assign the value that the expression on the right-side evaluated to (`{n:2}`), to the reference that `foo.x` resolved to in step 1 (**before** `foo` was assigned a new value). Which is also the same as `bar.x`, because of the assignment `bar = foo` on the line before.

When this is done, the original object, that `bar` is still a reference to, will have an `x` property that references the second object created. `foo` is also a reference to that second object, so `foo === bar.x`.

Comment: Looks like we have a winner.

Comment: how does `foo.x = (foo = {n: 2})` even make sense shouldn't that be the opposite, I just tested that in chrome too and it has the same results

Comment: @johnny5 It wouldn't make sense if `foo` wasn't already an object, but it is, from the first statement.

Comment: Best answer in whole duplicate questions link.

Comment: @Paulpro
is foo.x = foo = {n: 2}; breaks down to foo.x = {n: 2}; foo = {n: 2}; ?

Answer (score 8):

Because the property access `foo.x` on the left is evaluated before the right-hand side.

Let's make it more clear what your code actually does, by giving new names to the temporary expressions being evaluated:

```
var foo0 = {n: 1};
var foo1 = {n: 2};
foo0.x = foo1;
foo0 = foo1;
console.log(foo0.x);
```

Hence `foo0.x` is `foo1.x` is `undefined`.

In your original code, you can see that `bar.x` is `{n: 2}`, confirming this explanation.

Comment: I now see this is correct but it doesn't surprise me it's confusing people.

Answer (score 4):

According to the JavaScript spec, left hand side is always evaluated first:

> 12.14.4 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation
>
> *AssignmentExpression*<sub>[In, Yield]</sub> : *LeftHandSideExpression*<sub>[?Yield]</sub> = *AssignmentExpression*<sub>[?In, ?Yield]</sub>
>
> If *LeftHandSideExpression* is neither an *ObjectLiteral* nor an *ArrayLiteral*, then
>   1. Let *lref* be the result of evaluating *LeftHandSideExpression*.

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation

It can be clearly seen if you add another reference to the `foo` object:

```
var ref = {n:1};
var foo = ref;
var bar = foo;
foo.x = foo = {n: 2};
```

`ref.x` exists because `foo.x` refers to the unmodified value of `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you re-assigned foo to an object with a single property, `{ n: 2 }`.

In JavaScript, expressions are evaluated from right to left. So when you try to access `foo.x`, you are trying to get the value of `x` from newly assigned value of foo, `{ n: 2 }`, which is `undefined`.

Comment: Then what does "foo.x = "... do?

Comment: @djechlin it gets assigned to foo, but then foo is overriden to an object with out an x value